# Замена части массива numpy на другой массив

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть массив формой `a = (5, 1)`. Я беру часть массива `b = a[0:4]`. Изменяю его, и у меня получается массив `b = (8, 1)`. Теперь массивом b нужно заменить элементы, которые я брал у массива а.

```
a[0:4] = b - таким способом не получается.
```

Comment: А нужно именно заменить? Причём куском другого размера? Проще наверное новый массив создать из нужных элементов.

Comment: Нужно чтобы элементы нетронутые в начале, так и остались нетронутыми. Да, как вариант, можно брать лишние элементы в начале, и добавлять после всех операций, но может есть способ проще

Comment: Приведите всё-таки конкретный пример не с формой, а с содержанием массивов, а то всё-равно не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это точно numpy-массивы? Тогда так:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b=np.array([8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
a=np.hstack((b,a[4:]))
print(a)
```

Результат:

```
[8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 5]
```